# How to install Zebra ZXP 3 Printer in Windows without printer

Tags: windows, printing, zebra-printers

While investigating customer problem with Zebra ZXP Series 3 Card printers, I tried to install the printer in Windows. I do not have the actual device at hand, but it is also not needed because the problem we are chasing is some kind of spooler resource exhaustion when the application sends jobs to paused printer.

The OS is Windows 7 x64 and I got the drivers from [ZXP Series 3 product page](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printers/card/zxp-series-3.html)

I succeeded installing the drivers in system but while trying to Add Local Printer, either "Zebra ZXP Series 3 Network Card Printer" or "Zebra ZXP Series 3 USB Card Printer" I get error "Unable to install printer. Operation could
not be completed (error 0x0000000d)." There is nothing extra in the Event Log.

I have tried different port types, like FILE:, network etc. I guess the printer driver wants to have some kind of bi-directional communication with the device during setup and when that fails, the setup does not continue? Is there a way to circumvent such problem or should I conclude that the driver is simply temperamental and I need to go looking for a physical device?

Comment: I did made a program that can print to the printer without installing a driver using the SDK of zebra.